# Textmate and Rails (Rails3) not working for "Call Generate Script"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, textmate, generator

### Problem:

The rails UI interface for generating scripts bundle in Textmate is not working.

### Description:

In a rails document:
"**Bundles**"> "**Ruby on Rails**"> "**Call Generate Script**" and choose "**Controller**" then type
"**index**" > "**index**" and submit.
A window appears telling me: "**Done Generating controller**".
Yet when I browse through my directories **nothing new has been created**.

### Screenshot:

I take a screenshot of what happens during the generation process:
http://img152.imageshack.us/i/capturedcran20110201003.png/

### Versions:

ruby -v: **ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0**]
rails -v: **Rails 3.0.3**
I tried the same with an RVM environment by following this tutorial:
(http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/textmate/)
The result is the same.

Regards,
Guillaume.

Answer (score 2):

You have to slightly modifiy the bundle to make it work with the Rails 3 generate scripts. Have a look at my modifications on GitHub:

https://github.com/dhoelzgen/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle

Answer (score 0):

The error there says that there's "No such file or directory -- script/generate". This leads me to beleive that you're using Rails 3, where the command is now `rails generate` or `rails g` for short. Upgrade your Ruby on Rails TextMate bundle (follow [the instructions on the GitHub Page](https://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle)) or alternatively run `rails g controller [name]` from the command line.

Comment: And by chance does it works with you? Because I have already update my "Ruby on Rails.tmbundle", I have also update all my tmbundle with the SVN repository and it still doesn't work. So now I prefer to ask is what someone has already managed to make it run with rails3 syntax. If so then I can continue to seek what it wrong with me and may have to reinstall a fresh installation. But else I have to give up and I will turn to another solution. What would be a shame because I thought it was the editor of choice for developing with Rails.